# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: 7% with .replace

Tags: jquery, console

When trying to .replace the % in my string, I get the error "**Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: 7% with .replace**" What am I missing? OR is there a better way to do this?

```
//prints 7%
var percent = $("#sgE-123456-1-123-element :checked").attr("title");

// I'd like to remove the % so I can use the value to multiply
var percent_removed = $(percent).text().replace('%','');

//prints error
console.log(percent_removed);
```

Thanks in advance! (:ᘌꇤ⁐ꃳ 三

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be to simply remove the last character using slice().

this would give something like:

```
var percent_removed = percent.slice(0,-1);
```